# Capistrano deploy/assets on Rails 3.1 fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, capistrano, asset-pipeline

I added the this line `load 'deploy/assets'` to my Capfile to deploy assets with Rails 3.1.

Capistrano gets to this line

`* executing "cd /home/deploy/armonia/stage/releases/20110928021521 && bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=stage RAILS_GROUPS=assets assets:precompile"`

then fails with

`Could not find multi_json-1.0.3 in any of the sources` which is weird because the gem is found when I run `bundle show multi_json` on my deployment server.

What causes this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed this by updating to bundler to 1.0.18, seems to be related to this https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/issues/81